# Using Quartz in a clustered environment

Tags: java, web-applications, quartz-scheduler, cluster-computing, job-scheduling

I'm looking to use the quartz scheduler in my application because I have a clustered environment and want to guarantee that only one instance of my job runs each hour.  My question is...Do I have to use a JDBC job store or some sort of "outside" storage of job data to guarantee that only once instance in my cluster runs the job at any given hour or is there more magic to Quartz that I am aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the JDBC-JobStore, or else the TerracottaJobStore to enable a mechanism for the nodes to communicate with each other (in the one case they communicate in the db tables, in the other via the Terracotta networking features).