# how to run a job in same thread across jvm in spring. the same job should not run multiple times

Tags: multithreading, spring

how to run a  job in same thread across JVM's in spring.  the same job should not run multiple times.
it should run only once.

Comment: Are you asking how to make sure that a piece of code that is identically deployed to multiple JVM runs only exactly once (in one randomly chosen JVM)?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a scheduler with cluster support. I believe Quartz can do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527548/using-quartz-in-a-clustered-environment?rq=1

Comment: yes, app is deployed in multiple JVM's and job should run only once.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402665/making-schedule-run-only-once-in-a-clustered-environment?lq=1