# Unable to store job because one already exists with this identification

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm new with Quartz.
I succeeded to install it and run it.
But I have an error when I run it for the second time because the job already exists with this identification.

Here my code :

```
public void scheduleJobs() throws Exception {

    try {
        int i = 0;

        scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();

        JobKey job1Key = JobKey.jobKey("job"+i, "my-jobs"+i);
        JobDetail job1 = JobBuilder
                .newJob(SimpleJob.class)
                .withIdentity(job1Key)
                .build();

        TriggerKey tk1 = TriggerKey.triggerKey("trigger"+i, "my-jobs"+i);
        Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity(tk1)
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute(11, 25))
                .build();

        scheduler.start(); // start before scheduling jobs
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job1, trigger1);
        i++;

        printJobsAndTriggers(scheduler);

    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while creating scheduler", e);
    }   
}
```

I tried to use an integer i to change the name but it does not work.
Do you have any idea how can I fix it?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can:

- check if the "job key" already exists, and remove the existing job before creating a new one:

  `scheduler.deleteJob(job1Key);`
- or create a new job with another key (in your case, each time you execute `scheduleJobs()`, variable `i` has the same value (`0`)
- or just re-use the same job (why would you create a new job if the old one is still good)
- or use the RAM Job Store, which does not persist jobs in database (each time you will use your software, you will have an empty job store)

It really depends on what you want to do with your jobs!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I do not want to store each job in my DB. I use quartz in clustering mode to run a function on tomcat each day at 00:00. So I have the choice between delete the job if it already exists or use the RAM Job Store, is that correct ?

Comment: @Majestic, if you are in clustering mode, you cannot use the RAM Job Store. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5530204/625158

Comment: Thank a lot - I'm using jdbcjobstore.

Answer (score 17):

Check for existing job before scheduling:

```
JobDetail job;
SimpleTrigger trigger;

//Create your trigger and job

Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
scheduler.start();

if (scheduler.checkExists(job.getKey())){
    scheduler.deleteJob(job.getKey());
}
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Answer (score 11):

This is not a direct answer to the specific code listed in the question, but I didn't notice it when searching elsewhere and thought this might be useful for future readers:

If you're in a situation where you have an *existing* `Job` but just want to add a *new* `Trigger`, you can call:

`scheduler.ScheduleJob(trigger);`

and it will add the `Trigger` to the `Job` without trying to recreate the `Job`. The only trick is that you have to make sure the `Trigger`'s `JobKey` is correct.

My overall code for this interaction looks roughly like:

```cs
IJobDetail job;   // Handed in
ITrigger trigger; // Handed in

// Keeping track of this because we need to know later whether it's new or not
var newJob = job == null;
if (newJob)
{
    job = JobBuilder.Create<TargetJob>()
                 .WithIdentity([whatever]) 
                 [.OtherConfiguration()]
                 .Build();
}

var trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .Create()
    .WithIdentity([whatever])
    // ** Gotcha #1: Make sure it's linked to the job **
    .ForJob(job.Key) 
    [.OtherConfiguration()]
    .Build();

if (newJob)
{
    _scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
else
{
    // ** Gotcha #2: Make sure you don't reschedule the job **
    _scheduler.ScheduleJob(trigger);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If anyone of you are facing the same issue and your solution is in C#. This is how you can fix this error.

This is where we configure the scheduler.

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    try {
        var scheduler = await GetScheduler();
        var serviceProvider = GetConfiguredServiceProvider();
        scheduler.JobFactory = new CustomJobFactory(serviceProvider);
        await scheduler.Start();
        await ConfigureDailyJob(scheduler);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        _logger.Error(new CustomConfigurationException(ex.Message));
    }
}
```

This is how we can configure the Job, please be noted that we are checking whether the job is already there, and if the `await scheduler.CheckExists(dailyJob.Key)` returns true, we delete that job info and create a new one with the same key.

```
private async Task ConfigureDailyJob(IScheduler scheduler) {
    var dailyJob = GetDailyJob();
    if (await scheduler.CheckExists(dailyJob.Key)) {
        await scheduler.DeleteJob(dailyJob.Key);
        _logger.Info($ "The job key {dailyJob.Key} was already existed, thus deleted the same");
    }
    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(dailyJob, GetDailyJobTrigger());
}
```

There are the supporting private functions.

```
private IJobDetail GetDailyJob() {
    return JobBuilder.Create < IDailyJob > ().WithIdentity("dailyjob", "dailygroup").Build();
}
private ITrigger GetDailyJobTrigger() {
    return TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("dailytrigger", "dailygroup").StartNow().WithSimpleSchedule(x = >x.WithIntervalInHours(24).RepeatForever()).Build();
}
```

You can get the complete source code from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/SibeeshVenu/Perfect-Scheduler).

Answer (score -1):

You can create new jobs by taking i as a static int. And instead of "job"+i it would be "job"+ Integer.toString(i) . It worked for me.